# PHP-FPM behaving strangely with Nginx on new webserver

Tags: nginx, debian, php-fpm

So, I'm moving over to a new webserver, primarily because CentOS will soon be no more, so I am switching over to Debian 10.

I have Nginx and PHP configured as I'd like, but am having a really strange problem.

PHP-FPM seems to be working as expected, at least on one domain (i.e. I have an info.php script which is working as you would imagine).

However, I have created a script to send mail via Mailgun over SMTP, and this can be run directly via CLI, but is not executed when the page is loaded over HTTP. But, the PHP-FPM configuration for both sites is identical, and the other site can run this fine. I can echo out on scripts just fine - it just stops working for some reason.

Here's my server directive for this site:

```
server {

        # Site information
        server_name             joshuaquinlan.co.uk www.joshuaquinlan.co.uk;
        root                    /var/web-root/joshuaquinlan.co.uk/www;
        index                   index.html;

        # Error page locations
        error_page              404 /404.html;
        error_page              500 502 503 504 /50x.html;

        # Set expires for images, CSS and JS
        location ~*  \.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|ico|css|js)$ {
                expires         365d;
        }

        location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        }

        location ~ \.php$ {
            include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php8.0-fpm.sock;
        }


    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/joshuaquinlan.co.uk/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/joshuaquinlan.co.uk/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot


}
server {
    if ($host = www.joshuaquinlan.co.uk) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    if ($host = joshuaquinlan.co.uk) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


        server_name             joshuaquinlan.co.uk www.joshuaquinlan.co.uk;
    listen 80;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot




}
```

and here's the script:

```php
<?php

error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE ^ E_DEPRECATED ^ E_STRICT);

require_once "Mail.php";

$host = "ssl://smtp.eu.mailgun.org";
$username = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";
$password = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";
$port = "465";
$to = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";
$email_from = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";
$email_subject = "Subject Line Here:" ;
$email_body = "whatever you like" ;
$email_address = "reply-to@example.com";

$headers = array ('From' => $email_from, 'To' => $to, 'Subject' => $email_subject, 'Reply-To' => $email_address);
$smtp = Mail::factory('smtp', array ('host' => $host, 'port' => $port, 'auth' => true, 'username' => $username, 'password' => $password));
$mail = $smtp->send($to, $headers, $email_body);


if (PEAR::isError($mail)) {
        echo("<p>" . $mail->getMessage() . "</p>");
} else {
        echo("<p>Message successfully sent!</p>");
}
?>
```

Any ideas?

Thanks,
Josh

Comment: You could have just switched to RHEL. As for the immediate problem, check your nginx and PHP logs.

Comment: Thanks for the comment @MichaelHampton. Turned out to just be a problem with my php.ini include_path. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

First, try changing the port to 587. Test that first and also check the php/nginx access and error logs.

You might not have the pear mail module installed.  Try `sudo pear install Mail`

Check out https://www.mailgun.com/blog/sending-email-using-the-mailgun-php-api/

Also, remove the ssl:// for testing.

Comment: Thanks for the comment! Turned out this was just an issue with my php.ini include_path (which wasn't properly configured).

Answer (score 0):

After checking `/var/log/nginx/error.log`, it seemed that the `include_path` set in my `php.ini` file was incorrect.

This was indeed the case. After adding `include_path ".:/usr/share/pear"` to `/etc/php/8.0/fpm/php.ini` and restarting `php-fpm`, the error was resolved.

Thanks to everyone for their comments.